# Hibernate não encontra classe "Driver" do JDBC do mysql em projeto Maven

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, eclipse

Olá pessoal criei um projeto maven no eclipse (com empacotamento WAR) e importei os pacotes de models já mapeados de outro projeto, logo em seguida criei uma classe pra "carregar" uma fábrica de persistência porém a mesma retorna o seguinte erro:

> ```
> set 19, 2017 10:02:47 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
> WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:267)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:231)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
>     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
>     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
>     at com.bluegestao.audisped.jpa.util.JpaUtilMaster.<clinit>(JpaUtilMaster.java:22)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:7)
> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [value=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver]
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:229)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:160)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:100)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:72)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:240)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
>     at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:257)
>     ... 15 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : value=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:217)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>     at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:226)
>     ... 27 more
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at com.bluegestao.audisped.jpa.util.JpaUtilMaster.getEntityManager(JpaUtilMaster.java:29)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:7)
> ```

Por eu estar usando Maven não era pra esse erro estar acontecendo, além disso testei os models em outro projeto com o hibernate funcional e não tive problemas(sem erro de mapeamento) já vi pessoas resolvendo adicionando no classpath do projeto mais assim não seria uma espécie de má prática? já que se a ideia de você ter um gerenciador de dependencias não seria ele a fazer esse trabalho por você? a propósito uso Tomcat.

Pom utilizado:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bluegestao</groupId>
    <artifactId>Projeto</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Hibernate(implementação do JPA) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Drive JDBC do banco MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Primefaces - Implementação 6.0 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Implementação do JSF -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.14</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Primefaces Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

 </project>
```

Comment: Poste o codigo do seu pom.xml, Verifique se o jar do mysql se encontra na sua pasta .m2 local

Comment: O cabeçalho não apareceu mas o conteúdo está aí, está sim inclusive já deletei tudo da pasta repository e gerei denovo mas não tive sucesso.

Comment: @William.Andrade foi só um ajuste de formatação =] Eu sempre prefiro colocar código em blocos que começam com 4 espaços. Botar dentro da tag `<code>` não surte o efeito esperado

Comment: Para ver o classpath de execução: `for (URL url: ((URLClassLoader) (Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())).getURLs()) { url.getPath(); }`; assim dá para saber quais os jars carregados

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado obrigado pelas respostas e edições, porém tive de formatar meu computador aqui da empresa e por algum motivo não tive problemas rodando o mesmo código, estava usando Ubuntu e agora estou usando Deepin e não tive problemas com o Hibernate, você faz alguma ideia do que acontece com uma pergunta que não tem solução aqui? kk

Answer (score 2):

Como você está subindo sua aplicação em um servidor Tomcat as bibliotecas comuns devem ficar configuradas na pasta **/lib** do servidor como é o caso do mysql.

Adicione o jar na pasta **/lib** do tomcat

Para encontrar o caminho da pasta lib va até o arquivo **/conf/catalina.properties** e procure a propriedade **common.loader**

Comment: Obrigado por responder mas como disse ao amigo acima precisei formatar a máquina aqui e quando rodei o mesmo código não tive problemas, mas me tire uma dúvida, fazendo como você disse eu teria de declarar minhas dependências como provided não é? achava que só servidores de aplicação tinham essa opção, bom saber de qualquer jeito